# Can I have an MVC Action as a ServiceMethod for an AutoCompleteExtender?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocompleteextender

Assuming Tools is my Controller, I specify '/Tools' in the ServicePath, and the action name 'GetToolsList' in the ServiceMethod. Can I fire an AutoCompleteExtender this way? How would I be able to pass the prefixText to the Action here? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it. Created an action that returned void, and JSON-serialized the output and wrote it into the response object so that it's read and shown in an AutoCompleteExtender.